# Where to place the ItemsPagingSource file in Android project MVVM?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose, android-mvvm, android-paging

I have an Android project where I use MVVM. This is the structure:

```
src
 \_ domain
     \_ model
     \_ repository
          \_ ItemsRepository
 \_ data
     \_ repository
          \_ ItemsRepositoryImpl
 \_ presentations
     \_ items
          \_ ItemsScreen
          \_ ItemsViewModel
```

Today I have implemented pagination and I have created a `ItemsPagingSource` class. Where in this structure should I place such a file to not break MVVM rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where in this structure should I place such a file to not break MVVM rules?

`PagingSource` is a *source* of *data* - hence it would go with your data layer.

Maybe `src/data/repository`.
Or `src/data/paging` if you want to get granular.

That said, there are no "MVVM rules" for you to break as far as organizing your code. That's up to your personal (or team) preference to organize things in the way that's most logical for you.

Comment: Can you please also help me with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76610116/where-to-place-the-myfirebasemessagingservice-file-in-android-project-mvvm)? Thanks in advance.