# Where to place the MyFirebaseMessagingService file in Android project MVVM?

Tags: android, firebase, mvvm, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-mvvm

I have an Android project where I use MVVM. This is the structure:

```
src
 \_ domain
     \_ model
     \_ repository
          \_ ItemsRepository
 \_ data
     \_ repository
          \_ ItemsRepositoryImpl
 \_ presentations
     \_ items
          \_ ItemsScreen
          \_ ItemsViewModel
```

Today I have implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging and I have created a `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class. Where in this structure should I place such a file? Where is the place that belongs to?

Comment: [Opinion] If you have a `services` package, independent from features, then you can use that. Or else a separate top level package `services`. For example: src -> domain, data, presentations, services -> MyFirebaseMessagingService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing here is that MVVM is a pattern and it is used in the presentation layer.

What you are seeking is where the service belongs when you are using a **Clean Architecture layer based module**.

The MyFirebaseMessagingService class doest **not belongs to presentation layer** obviously (because it has **nothing to do with the presentation of your app**).

**It should not be in the domain layer** because the domain layer should have only use cases, repository interfaces and model. + the service has **nothing to do with business logic**

So, the last layer is the **data** one and this is **where the service should be**.
If the service communicate with firebase to send / retrieve data it mean that the service is considered like a Data Source.
The purpose of repositories is to aggregate those data sources and to build a domain model.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. Voted-up. Looking  forward to see also other opinions. If that's the way I should use, I'll accept the answer.